REGEX to split address components using R - numbers in street/avenue names
Consider the following set of addresses to be split, contained in a variable called addresses:
RUA DOS PASSOS 1523 CS 2

AV CAXIAS, 02 CASA 05

AV 11 DE NOVEMBRO 2032 CASA 4

RUA 05 DE OUTUBRO, 25 CASA 02

The final output should be a table like so:



logradouro
no_logradouro
nu_logradouro
complemento




RUA DOS PASSOS 1523 CS 2
RUA DOS PASSOS
1523
CS 2


AV CAXIAS, 02 CASA 05
AV CAXIAS
02
CASA 05


AV 11 DE NOVEMBRO 2032 CASA 4
AV 11 DE NOVEMBRO
2032
CASA 4


RUA 05 DE OUTUBRO, 25 CASA 02
RUA 05 DE OUTUBRO
25
CASA 02



Some important points:

The presence of the comma on the addresses is not mandatory; some have them, some don't. I'd like for the final table to have no commas anywhere;
There can be trailing zeroes, although they are not mandatory.

My current attempt is as follows:
addresses <- c("RUA DOS PASSOS 1523 CS 2", "AV CAXIAS, 02 CASA 05", "AV 11 DE NOVEMBRO 2032 CASA 4", "RUA 05 DE OUTUBRO, 25 CASA 02")
regex <- "^(\\D+(?:(?!\\s\\d+\\s\\D).)*?)\\s(\\d+)(?:\\s+(.*))?$" 
result <- str_match(addresses, regex)
df_result <- data.frame(logradouro = addresses,
             no_logradouro = ifelse(is.na(result[, 2]), addresses, str_squish(result[, 2])),
             nu_logradouro = ifelse(is.na(result[, 3]), "", str_squish(result[, 3])),
             complemento = ifelse(is.na(result[, 4]), "", str_squish(result[, 4])))
  

and the output is:



logradouro
no_logradouro
nu_logradouro
complemento




RUA DOS PASSOS 1523 CS 2
RUA DOS PASSOS 1523 CS
2



AV CAXIAS, 02 CASA 05
AV CAXIAS, 02 CASA
05



AV 11 DE NOVEMBRO 2032 CASA 4
AV 11 DE NOVEMBRO
2032
CASA 4


RUA 05 DE OUTUBRO, 25 CASA 02
RUA 05 DE OUTUBRO,
25
CASA 02



As you can see, the REGEX works for the composite cases (i.e., "AV 11 DE NOVEMBRO 2032 CASA 4") but fails for the others. How can I adapt my REGEX to work on both cases, taking into account what I've discussed in this post?
In summary, the rules are that each address should be split into 3 parts, if possible: no_logradouro, which represents the name of street, avenue etc; nu_logradouro, which represents the number of the address and complemento which is everything else.

I am voting to close this because you haven't set out clear rules and the question contains the sentence, These examples are not exhaustive. These are hallmarks of a chameleon question. As it stands I think it's unlikely to prove edifying for anyone.

If you make the assumption that the complemento values start with CS or CASA then you can work backwards. Something like this will work
x <- c("RUA DOS PASSOS 1523 CS 2", "AV CAXIAS, 02 CASA 05", 
  "AV 11 DE NOVEMBRO 2032 CASA 4", "RUA 05 DE OUTUBRO, 25 CASA 02")

strcapture(
  "(.*?),?\\s(\\d+)\\s+((?:CASA|CS) \\d+)$", 
  x, 
  proto = data.frame(no_logradouro=character(), nu_logradouro=character(), complemento=character())
)

and returns
      no_logradouro nu_logradouro complemento
1    RUA DOS PASSOS          1523        CS 2
2         AV CAXIAS            02     CASA 05
3 AV 11 DE NOVEMBRO          2032      CASA 4
4 RUA 05 DE OUTUBRO            25     CASA 02

